# python .format(*str) returns 5348 instead of 50

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I have this code to format the received data from Serial port to 2 variables
it receives `'v=220f=50'` and format it to

```
 reads = ser.readline()                # data received is 'v=220f=50'         
 voltage = int('{2}{3}{4}'.format(*reads))
 freq = '{7}{8}'.format(*reads)
```

so `voltage = 220` and `freq = 50` but i get `voltage = 505048` and `freq = 5348` instead!, I tried casting them to `int()` but nothing changed. maybe it's some sort of encoding.

ps: I want to store them into a file so no need to cast them to integers:

```
fw.write('Voltage is: {0};\t  Frequency is: {1}\n'.format(voltage, freq))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a bytes object from `ser.readline()`. You should first convert to string with `.decode`:

```
>>> reads = b'v=220f=50'
>>> voltage = int('{2}{3}{4}'.format(*reads))
>>> voltage
505048
>>> voltage = int('{2}{3}{4}'.format(*reads.decode()))
>>> voltage
220
```

I would also suggest you look into parsing the values using regex. The current approach would easily break when the length of any of the values change.

Comment: thank you, `.decode()` solve it
and thank you about your suggestion, but I'll make sure the length stay the same by the arduino code